# ImportError after installing djangocms-blog: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils .encoding'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-cms

I currently installed `django-cms` and `djangocms-blog`. When I run `migrate`, it throws the following error. Some ressources suggest to install `six`, which however is already satisfied in my venv.

I use the latest Python, pip and django versions.

These are the guides I followed to set up [djangocms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html) and [djangocms-blog](https://djangocms-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Any solution to this?

```
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from html5lib>=0.999999999->djangocms
-text-ckeditor>=3.5->djangocms-blog) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from django>=1.1->django-taggit-templ
atetags->djangocms-blog) (3.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\p
rograms\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from django>=1.1->django-taggit-te
mplatetags->djangocms-blog) (0.3.0)
Collecting django-js-asset
  Downloading django_js_asset-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: djangocms-text-ckeditor, django-taggit-t
emplatetags, django-filer, easy-thumbnails, django-sekizai, django-treebeard, dj
ango-classy-tags, djangocms-admin-style, django-appdata
  Building wheel for djangocms-text-ckeditor (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for djangocms-text-ckeditor: filename=djangocms_text_ckeditor-3.
9.0-py3-none-any.whl size=2009460 sha256=7f2a93b1858ad9c776ea9d286bf96924070a8d7
03ffb5d4510f3b74d39ca57d2
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\0c\7b\1e\e3
908562c925cdc1dbcd7c4bd2447f8a11f6716a7d99f3c04b
  Building wheel for django-taggit-templatetags (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-taggit-templatetags: filename=django_taggit_templatet
ags-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl size=7824 sha256=798816cf8c5154b3cd9d133dd906c8e40945
53de30f114a76fe8829d08a7c66c
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\82\a4\66\54
1f4c683657632200e1e8ea3a89698e88ede94c1232365f00
  Building wheel for django-filer (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-filer: filename=django_filer-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl s
ize=1572351 sha256=89983e63dedf4ecef67b3c0f929f9cf53281cd232a8afa72e9c97e2b3d9e3
d34
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\01\26\cd\d8
64a98a0a882ae18c7c0551af158f82193a7e5daa88a86572
  Building wheel for easy-thumbnails (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for easy-thumbnails: filename=easy_thumbnails-2.7-py2.py3-none-a
ny.whl size=65532 sha256=b0c81ae967ea8073bba11192946e3e2a4af3928c5be5010445c6cf6
d21f37964
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\e4\3f\d4\3c
7af17dfe56f754d3fe9a3c610aaeff28eaad840778039d1f
  Building wheel for django-sekizai (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-sekizai: filename=django_sekizai-1.1.0-py3-none-any.w
hl size=8501 sha256=895b43796abbfb5a8f4525140a3f96616b0a97ae46f1d17d1ef58ad5acdb
c671
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5f\a4\f3\ba
2e3b26fd0c6da68f23e2adfc90a52cd04e3c0a877fe7b295
  Building wheel for django-treebeard (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-treebeard: filename=django_treebeard-4.3.1-py2.py3-no
ne-any.whl size=104160 sha256=96537f1f9de03bb552d47ddb90ebfaf6016d6b771f3e12605d
d706f8a67880ed
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\76\63\57\ba
77f284b71e8aa5afd08c85f1968bcfdc8106f12837ce32eb
  Building wheel for django-classy-tags (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-classy-tags: filename=django_classy_tags-1.0.0-py3-no
ne-any.whl size=14275 sha256=0b6b349b241b4a668360c2de1fbf931de6110451365ceaf0ef1
33a52298c8eb8
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\64\40\96\8c
0ee90f1bf065766a881f22ee8bc54afeb3323989569d4c90
  Building wheel for djangocms-admin-style (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for djangocms-admin-style: filename=djangocms_admin_style-1.5.0-
py3-none-any.whl size=400280 sha256=791618cc13eb3d1347d84c54a12dce88323f656aa64a
2451712ce3c74f32bd34
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\c6\55\98\79
73149944c17dbb19598c419fb47139e1f8984bc66bd40731
  Building wheel for django-appdata (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-appdata: filename=django_appdata-0.2.2-py3-none-any.w
hl size=12418 sha256=42dd18e970075a3f0c33737b5955ad464922c155ed70f5b1eb76d7ddb41
b17a7
  Stored in directory: c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\4e\fa\87\57
d4ab1d1df54f32b3f74bb567a632f76662b81a270d4eb82a
Successfully built djangocms-text-ckeditor django-taggit-templatetags django-fil
er easy-thumbnails django-sekizai django-treebeard django-classy-tags djangocms-
admin-style django-appdata

// First error

ERROR: django-appdata 0.2.2 has requirement Django<3.0,>=1.8, but you'll have dj
ango 3.0.6 which is incompatible.


Installing collected packages: django-formtools, django-classy-tags, django-seki
zai, django-treebeard, djangocms-admin-style, django-cms, html5lib, djangocms-te
xt-ckeditor, django-taggit, django-templatetag-sugar, django-taggit-templatetags
, django-js-asset, django-mptt, django-polymorphic, easy-thumbnails, Unidecode,
django-filer, django-meta, djangocms-apphook-setup, lxml, django-sortedm2m, djan
go-appdata, aldryn-apphooks-config, django-taggit-autosuggest, django-parler, dj
angocms-blog
Successfully installed Unidecode-1.1.1 aldryn-apphooks-config-0.5.3 django-appda
ta-0.2.2 django-classy-tags-1.0.0 django-cms-3.7.2 django-filer-1.7.1 django-for
mtools-2.2 django-js-asset-1.2.2 django-meta-1.6.1 django-mptt-0.11.0 django-par
ler-2.0.1 django-polymorphic-2.1.2 django-sekizai-1.1.0 django-sortedm2m-3.0.0 d
jango-taggit-1.2.0 django-taggit-autosuggest-0.3.8 django-taggit-templatetags-0.
2.5 django-templatetag-sugar-1.0 django-treebeard-4.3.1 djangocms-admin-style-1.
5.0 djangocms-apphook-setup-0.4.1 djangocms-blog-1.1.0 djangocms-text-ckeditor-3
.9.0 easy-thumbnails-2.7 html5lib-1.0.1 lxml-4.5.0

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\aldryn_apphooks_config\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

// Second error

ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils
.encoding' (C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\utils\encoding.py)

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>python -m pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\jonas\appdata\local\programs\pyth
on\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.14.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python_2_unicode_compatible` was removed from Django in 3.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis

It looks like you need to update one of your packages that's using it. From the traceback, that would be `aldryn_apphooks_config`. I'm not sure where that comes from, would need some more details for that. I would suggest checking your requirements file and trying to upgrade packages until it works, but you might have to end up removing some.

Comment: tried it after removing `aldryn_apphooks_config`, then `migrate` tells me that this package is missing. Tried to upgrade this package, then it deleted my django 3.0 and installed 2.2, which did end up in a different error. It occured after installing djangocms and djangocms-blog. So if they install it along as dependency it should be required and working with the latest django & python releases (according to their docs), hmh

Comment: It can be a hassle dealing with old packages that aren't maintained anymore, but there's not generally a solution other than messing around until it works. What I'd suggest is trying to find which package is using `aldryn_apphooks_config` and try to upgrade that, and so on until you get to the root packages. They may have dropped the dependency, or it may be that they too are unmaintained.

Answer (score 1):

In that case it was an out-of-date dependency which was solved by the owner meanwhile after my request:

https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/issues